# Seamless git svn setup

Tags: svn, git, version-control, git-svn

I am a power git user and a happy one at that.

Now, I'm forced to use svn and I am not exactly happy to do so. Not so comfortable using `git svn` yet.

So, here is the setup I'd like and want.

- I use a git repo, that is git in all ways with many local branches.
- I create multiple branches in git regularly and merge, let git handle all of it.
- I want to send selected git branch as an svn branch with everything mirrored.
- When I delete a local svn mirrored git branch, the svn branch gets deleted too.

The underlining point is that, I want git to do all the hard work of merge and branch and just push to the svn and make it a store.

Sounds like I'm asking for a git-svn tutorial. Except I have gone thro them many times, and yet, I face errors while I do `git svn rebase` and `git svn commit` very often and it always seems to talk to trunk alone.

What I want is mirrored svn commands sent and mirrored branches.

Comment: How did you set up your git-svn repo?  Is it tracking standard svn **trunk / tag / branch conventions**?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266395/git-svn-how-do-i-create-a-new-svn-branch-via-git) for a introduction to `git svn branch`  and [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839606/delete-a-svn-branch-via-git) for how to delete remote branches - or below for a complete summary of the basics of `git svn` (including the information from the two questions mentioned).

To give you a more complete tutorial (the complete setup to cover local and remote branches, commiting, merging local branches - see below the horizontal line for just the branch setup), here's how to work easily with a svn repo:

- Initialize your local git repo with `git svn clone <url>`, either with paramter `-s` (stdlayout) or with the parameters `--trunk, --tags, --branches` to specify the directory of the trunk, tags and branches inside the svn dir.

`-s` means, the svn repo has a directory layout like this

```
/trunk
/branches/new_feature
/branches/long_fix
/tags/0.0.9
/tags/0.1.0
```

If not, you can specify the location of the *trunk*, *branches* and *tags* with the arguments provided above.

When you clone the repo, you will automatically land in a local branch called *master*, which will automatically track the *trunk*.

In this, you do your commits just like you would not know you cloned the repo with `git svn`, except you **do not push commits**:

- Use `git commit` to do commits to your branch
- Use `git branch <branch name>` to create local branches
- Use `git merge <branch name>` to merge changes from local branches
- etc.

You do not need to worry about you are in a `git svn`-repo, **until you want to push your changes**.

From the setup above, we have the local branch *master* which is tracking *trunk*. So after doing commits inside the local *master*-branch, they can be pushed to the *trunk* with the following command:

- `git svn dcommit` (inside your local branch *master*)

(Note the **d** in `dcommit`).

To test where you commits would go, do

- `git svn dcommit -n`

---

Now comes the interesting part: create branches on your side that are tracked. Really simple reading [the question above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266395/git-svn-how-do-i-create-a-new-svn-branch-via-git), I'll just copy and paste the example:

- `git svn branch -n  -m "Branch for authentication bug" auth_bug`

Note that this example has the `-n` flag which only does a dry run. Remove that flag to do it for real. The command creates the branch *auth_bug* on the svn repo in the *branches*-directory you set up above, and

- `git checkout -b auth_bug auth_bug`

creates a local branch *auth_bug* (first param) and lets it follow the remote branch *auth_bug* (second param), which is mapped to the dir `/branches/auth_bug` on the svn repo. The remote branch *auth_bug* exists, because you created it with the `git svn branch`-command (and could be any other branch already existing).

Inside this local branch *auth_bug*, all your commits will be pushed to the svn repo in the branches dir `/branches/auth_bug` when doing `git svn dcommit` (test it by appending `-n` to the command.)

To delete a branch (I've not done it before), it looks like `git svn` does not handle this for you, so according to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839606/delete-a-svn-branch-via-git), you have to to the following directly using the `svn` command:

- `svn rm $URL/branches/the_branch`

This deletes the branch from the remote svn repo, and then you have to remove it from your local git repo, depending on it was a branch (like in the command above) or a tag:

```
git branch -D -r the_branch
rm -rf .git/svn/the_branch
```

or

```
git branch -D -r tags/the_tag
rm -rf .git/svn/tags/the_tag
```

---

To update your branch with changes from the upstream svn branch ("pull"), you can rebase your branch on top of the change with:

- `git svn rebase`

This fetches new commits in svn, rebases your branch and plays back your local commits (if any).

Comment: Awesome thanks! I guess, I can still push the git branches including the master to other git repos, if I dont want to deal with svn in the meanwhile? And the git svn rebase would rebase current commits in the master based on what was on the trunk.

Comment: It may also be useful to add the --prefix parameter when you clone so you don't face any problems with local branch names having the same name as remote branches in the future:  
`git svn clone <url> --prefix=<your_prefix>`
  
I tend to use "svn/" as prefix so all my remote branches are "svn/somthing"

Comment: What if I want to "pull" from the svn? How do I do that?

Comment: Is there an easy way to see the tracked svn branch without running `git svn dcommit -n` ?

Comment: So to initialize with `git svn clone`, do I have to do that in a separate directory from my current svn directory?  Or do I just do that in the existing svn repo dir.

Answer (score 3):

Intead of *git-svn* you may try *SubGit*.

[SubGit](http://subgit.com/) is a Git-SVN bi-directional server-side mirror.

If you have local access to Subversion repository, you can install SubGit into it just like this:

```
$ subgit configure $SVN_REPOS
# Adjust $SVN_REPOS/conf/subgit.conf to specify your branches and tags
# Adjust $SVN_REPOS/conf/authors.txt to specify git & svn authors mapping
$ subgit install $SVN_REPOS
...
$ INSTALLATION SUCCESSFUL
```

SubGit converts Subversion repository into Git (it works in opposite direction as well) and installs SVN and Git hooks. As result Subversion and Git repositories are synchronized: every commit and push starts hooks that convert incoming modifications immediately.

Here are some benefits of using SubGit:

1. SubGit automatically converts svn:ignore properties into .gitignore files, svn:eol-style and svn:mime-type properties to .gitattributes;
2. SubGit automatically converts merge-tracking information from Git repository to proper svn:mergeinfo property updates;
3. One may use any Git client to work with SubGit-powered Git repository, all the changes are immediately propagated to Subversion counterpart.

For more details please refer to [SubGit documentation](http://subgit.com/documentation/) and [git-svn](http://subgit.com/documentation/gitsvn.html) comparison page.

And here's the description of how standard Git operations are reflected in Subversion repository:

1. Create branch *foo* and push it to the original Git repository:

   ```
   $ git checkout -b foo master
   $ git commit -a -m "Implement feature foo"
   $ git push origin foo
   ```

   As soon as push is done, Subversion repository gets *^/branches/foo* branch copied from *^/trunk* with appropriate modifications.
2. Merge branch *foo* to *master*:

   ```
   $ git checkout master 
   $ git merge foo
   $ git push
   ```

   At this moment a new revision created for branch *^/trunk* with appropriate modifications including svn:mergeinfo update:

   ```
   + /branches/foo:rX-rY
   ```
3. Delete branch from remote repository:

   ```
   $ git push origin +:refs/heads/foo
   ```

   After that *^/branches/foo* is deleted in SVN repository.

SubGit is a commercial product. It is free for open-source and academic projects and also for projects with up to 10 committers.

Disclaimer: I'm one of SubGit developers.

Comment: What does the variable `$SVN_REPOS` stand for?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky `$SVN_REPOS` is a path to Subversion repository directory. Please note this answer is a bit out-dated, SubGit now supports remote mirror mode which does not require local access to Subversion repository. For more information on this mode, please refer to SubGit documentation: http://www.subgit.com/remote-book.html