# How to remove duplicated commits in a git svn tree?

Tags: git, git-svn, git-commit

I am working with a SVN server using git SVN.
I struggled to created a tag so I had a look at the tree.
I noticed that my tree is messed up: all commits appear twice. Once in the red "branch" and once in the purple on:

[image]

Before posting this I cleaned a lot of branches using:

```
git branch -D useless_remote_branch
git gc
```

But for this one I don't know what to do to get a clean history.

**How could I get back to a linear history with only the red "branch"?**

I can delete the tag on the SVN side if needed.

Thank you!

---

### EDIT

Here is what I got after the solution suggested by @VonC and a `git svn tag` command:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure you [have properly deleted the purple branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1839809/6309) (both on git and svn), make sure you delete the tag as well (both on git and svn)

```
svn rm $URL/tags/the_tag
git branch -D -r tags/the_tag
rm -rf .git/svn/tags/the_tag
```

That way, none of the commits from the purple branch won't be referenced by any commit from the red branch.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I think I tried that earlier but it failed (I tried so many things I don't remember them all!). Now it works! I probably did something wrong when tagging for SVN... Thanks again :)